# blender fliped face texture question

Tags: texturing, faces

I created this small room and for the door I used a Boolean, now the problem is that I can texture the inner part of the this model as the faces are flipped off the walls and ceiling, and when I try to flip them then the outer part of the faces got flipped and cant texture the outer wall part.

Is there any method to fix this or do I have to create this again?

[image]

Comment: did you try  to `Recalculate Normals` in `Edit Mode`? Also if your shader are not too fancy (no transparence, glass etc) I don't think that's a big issue to have backfaces.

Comment: In Edit mode, you can select the faces whose normals you want to flip then go Mesh->Normals->Flip and it will only flip the selected faces.